# Wordpress Multisite : Theme doesn't work for sub site

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I am new to wordpress multisite. I have just bought 3 paid themes and uploaded each of them.

each theme as asked to upload some kind of sample data with it, so we did it.

Now when we activate any of the theme for network theme it works like charm.

Now have created 2-3 subsites also and when we try to assign these themes to any of the sub sites , the themes applies to it but doesn't show up with all dummy data uploaded. It always show blog kind of page with the theme design.

So my question is do we have to upload sample data for each sub-site?

Any way to get rid of this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The sub sites do not share data. Each site has it's own posts. That's not an 'issue' that's the design of Multisite.

Comment: @helgatheviking: But if i have added all dummy data to a theme and then do it `NETWORK ENABLE` then the theme with the data should be available for all sub sites , right?

Comment: You don't add dummy data to a theme. A theme is merely presentation layer for the data. Demo posts/pages are added to a specific site. Even demo theme options (like those set in the customizer) are site-specific.